# Create multiple Pie Highcharts for multiple series

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6, highcharts, pie-chart

I am trying to draw a highchart using JSON data. My data has multiple series. Because of that 2 pie charts are created overlapping each other. Is there a way for me to draw the multiple highcharts next to each other instead?

My JSON, code and working example of the pie charts overlapping each other:

```js
let data = [{
    "name": "cakes",
    "data": [
        [
            "us",
            149045
        ],
        [
            "es",
            41746
        ],
        [
            "uk",
            37640
        ],
        [
            "au",
            16594
        ]
    ],
    "marker": {
        "symbol": "circle"
    }
}, {
    "name": "pie",
    "data": [
        [
            "us",
            128845
        ],
        [
            "es",
            35752
        ],
        [
            "uk",
            32246
        ],
        [
            "au",
            14333
        ]
    ],
    "marker": {
        "symbol": "circle"
    }
}]

Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            type: 'pie',
            zoomType: 'xy'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    // format: '{series.data[0]} <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
                }
            },
        },
        series: data
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

How do I get pie charts next to each other rather than one on top of the other? One for `cakes` and one for `pies`?

Comment: like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/gseqwfz3/) ?

Comment: @Swati, thank you for your response. This works fine when there are 2 series. What if I have more than 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create multiple charts with dynamically calculated styles:

```
data.forEach(function(dataEl) {
    const createdDiv = document.createElement('div');
    createdDiv.style.display = 'inline-block';
    createdDiv.style.width = 100 / data.length + '%'

    mainContainer.appendChild(createdDiv);

    Highcharts.chart(createdDiv, {
        ...,
        series: [dataEl]
    });
});
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/jn4p2gq8/

---

Or one chart with dynamically calculated `center` property for each series.

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.pie.center